# php zip creation function is not working on window

Tags: php, window

I wrote a zip creation function in PHP. It works fine on Ubuntu but when I it throws an error when I use it on a Windows machine.

```
<?php

    $Zip = new ZipArchive();
    $filelocation = 'update';
    $Ziplocation = 'ZipVila/ZipEx.zip';
    $Zipfolder = 'ZipVila';

    $Zip->open($Ziplocation, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
    $files = scandir($filelocation);

    print_r($files);

    unset($file[0], $file[1]); // Windows throws an "object file is not defined" error in this line   

    foreach ($files as $file) {

        $Zip->addfile($filelocation."/{$file}", $file);
        echo "File Added";

    }

    $Zip->close();

    echo "Zip Closed";

?>
```

Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: What is the error it shows? Does the directory ZipVila exist? Dir name is case sensitive on non windows systems.

Comment: Directory exists and the program gives the error that the object file is not created

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have an error in

```
unset($file[0], $file[1]);
```

because $file is not set yet so you can unset it, try this

```
unset($files[0], $files[1]);
```

Comment: please mark this as the correct solution so this thread no more exists in the unanswered section.

Comment: also i was having another problem that on ubantu my code was creating 2 unknown files in my zip and now that problem solved to, thank you so much.....